# Sum $‎‎\sum_{n=0}^{5‎}{n}{(n+1)}‎‎$

Tags: summation

Since this series seems to be 0,2,6,12,20 and 30 there isn't a common difference that is identical between each term - it in itself seems to increase by 2 each time.

I can't use $S_n=\frac{n[2a+(n-1)d]}{2}$ since I don't know what to do about the common difference.

Answer is supposed to be 112.

$$‎‎\sum_{n=0}^{5‎}{n}{(n+1)}‎‎$$

Comment: If there are just 6 terms in the sum, can't you compute it directly ?

Comment: @KevinQuirin and what if instead of $5$ you had $27$?

Comment: I did - it makes 70 not 112. :|

Comment: I have seen these types of finite sums with very little terms pop up on this site. Is this usual for education outside of england?

Comment: @Chinny84 - I am in England.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the formula
$$\sum_{n=0}^N n^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$$
together with the AP formula to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^5n(n+1)=\sum_{n=0}^5n^2+\sum_{n=0}^5n=\frac{5\times6\times11}{6}+\frac{5\times6}{2}=55+15=70\ .$$
On the other hand, since you have just worked out all the terms and there are not many of them, you may as well just add them up...

The answer would be $112$ if the upper limit of summation was $6$ instead of $5$.

Comment: OMG - if the upper limit was 6... You might have found the only typo in this textbook - it's been perfect in the Answers section - and it definitely says upper limit is 5.

Comment: BTW - I'm sorry but you're talking way above my head. We've only got two summation formulas that we've learned - the one I mentioned in the question and n(first +last)/2 so I don't understand the squaring of n or any of the "all over 6"... I'm new to sequences/series.

Comment: I'm going to assume there was a typo in the book and the upper limit was 6, so thanks.

Comment: The second formula I used (the AP formula) comes straight out of the one you quoted if you substitute appropriate values of $a,d$ and $n$.  The first may be new to you, but it's just a formula, and quite a useful one, worth learning.

Answer (score 1):

First, that is not a *series*, it is just a *sum*: a series has infinitely many terms, while your expression has just 6.

Second, just add up these 6 numbers, you don't need any smart formula here.

If you really want to be smart, rewrite your sum as $\sum \limits _{n=0} ^5 n^2 + \sum \limits _{n=0} ^5 n$ and use that $\sum \limits _{n=0} ^N n^2 = \frac {N(N+1)(2N+1)} 6$ and $\sum \limits _{n=0} ^N n = \frac {N(N+1)} 2$.

Comment: The distinction between "series" and "sum" is artificial: I can add infinitely many zeros and call it a series.

Comment: I don't think we're "supposed" to just add them - and I make it 70, not the solution in the book which says 112.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this involves converting the sum to a sum of a telescoping series and a trivial series.  Consider

$$(n+1)^3-n^3 = 3 n^2+3 n+1 = 3 n (n+1)+1 \implies n (n+1) = \frac13 [(n+1)^3-n^3] - \frac13 $$

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} n (n+1) = \frac13 \sum_{n=1}^{N} [(n+1)^3-n^3] - \frac13 \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1 = \frac13 [(N+1)^3 - 1] - \frac13 N$$

You can simplify this to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} n (n+1) = \frac13 (N^3 + 3 N^2 +2 N) = \frac13 N (N+1)(N+2)$$

Plug in $N=5$ to get your answer.